# Specific Docker Command in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to start a Bro container in a Pod.  In docker I would normally run something like this:
docker run -d --net=host --name bro
Is there something in the container spec that would replicate that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [hostNetwork option of the API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L890) to run a pod on the host's network.